# How to intake strings and input them to a graph?

Tags: c++, string, input, graph-theory

The problem I am trying to solve has to do with a social network exercise where a person has one best friend and the rest are friends of that friend.

I have been stuck on this problem for a couple days now on how to intake input and get it to a graph.  The general idea is to apply this to a graph and find the strongly connected components, which is essentially when (shown below) a particular person's best friend (name right after their name) has friends that two people may have in common. Like shown, John and Lucas would be a strongly connected component since Lucas's best friend Mike is also a friend of a friend for John. (I know, its a little confusing)

- First name of line will always be the person in question.
- Second name of line will always be that person's best friend.
- Any names after that are "friends of friends" (this could be from 0 -> 100, the example shown only has one for each person for simplicity)

Test Case:

4

John Bob Mike

Emma Noah Ava

Ben Henry Sarah

Lucas Mike Sophia

Test Case Output:
2

**Now, this wouldn't be too much of an issue if it were limited to two friends, however the amount of names after the best friend's name can be 0 to 100. What are some of your suggestions to approach the intake of this data into a graph?** (again, I am just asking for tips on formatting the input to be put into a graph, finding strongly connected components is already solved.)

What I have so far to get input into individual people:

```
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore();

    int amount = n;
    vector<string> s(amount);

    for (int i = 0; i < amount ; i++) //intake the whole line of text
    {
        string all;
        getline(cin, all);
        s[i] = all;
    }

    map<string, vector<string>> network;//possibly use a map? 
    vector<string> people;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) //breaking up the string into words
    {
        string person = "";
        
        for (int j = 0; j < s[i].length(); j++)
        {
            if (s[i][j] == ' ')
            {
                people.push_back(person);
                person = ""; //setting string back to empty
            }
            else 
            {
                person += s[i][j];
            }                    
        }

    }
```

I am stuck on how to get the logic for the edges. A overview would be 'n' amount of nodes, but the issues is getting the edges all formatted for the graph. This is the part that I am stuck on the most. The code I have will basically separate out the string into words, but how can I meaningfully attach that to someone in terms of edges? Thanks for taking the time to check this problem out.

Comment: Define what does it mean "to be connected", design a structure, and fill in the data? Like `struct Person { std::string:: bestFriend; std::vector<std::string> friends; std::set<Person*> connections; };` and then fill in the `connections` based on your logic.

Comment: I was referring to connecting edges and nodes together for the particular graph. The technical question would be regarding said input, what direction would you propose to capture it as a system of nodes and edges. It isn't an issue related to code, but rather the approach to intaking it as a graph. Sorry if it seems like I am asking for a tutorial, I do not believe my question was structured in such a way. I am specifically asking for potential approaches to getting said input to a graph so then I can apply an algorithm to it. @Sam Varshavchik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two types of connections between people: "best friend" ( bf ) or "friend of friend" ( ff )

So you will need an edge attribute so that you can capture the distinction.

The edge list for the graph for your example would therefor be

| v1 | v2 | atribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Bob | bf |
| John | Mike | ff |
| Emma | Noah | bf |
| Emma | Ava | ff |
| Ben | Henry | bf |
| Ben | Sarah | ff |
| Lucas | Mike | bf |
| Lucas | Sophia | ff |

This code:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/// @brief A graph edge
class edge
{
public:
    std::string v1;
    std::string v2;
    std::string attr;

    edge(
        const std::string &s1,
        const std::string &s2,
        const std::string &sattr)
        : v1(s1),
          v2(s2),
          attr(sattr)
    {
    }
    void display()
    {
        std::cout << v1 << " | "<< v2 <<" | "<< attr << "\n";
    }
};

/// @brief define graph type

typedef std::vector<edge> graph_t;

/// @brief split line into space delimited tokens
/// @param line 
/// @return vector of tokens

std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const std::string &line)
{
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    std::stringstream sst(line);
    std::string a;
    while (getline(sst, a, ' '))
        ret.push_back(a);
    return ret;
}

/// @brief Output text listing graph edges
/// @param[in] g 

void display(graph_t& g)
{
    std::cout << "v1 | v2 | atribute\n|---|---|---|\n";
    for( edge& e : g )
    {
        e.display();
    }
}
/// @brief read graph from input file
/// @param[in/out] g graph to add edges to
/// @param fname input file path

void read(
    graph_t& g,
    const std::string &fname)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(fname);
    if (!ifs.is_open())
        throw std::runtime_error("no input file");
    std::string line;
    while (getline(ifs, line))
    {
        auto vtoken = tokenize(line);
        g.push_back( edge( vtoken[0],vtoken[1],"bf"));
        for( int k = 2; k<vtoken.size(); k++ )
            g.push_back( edge( vtoken[0],vtoken[k],"ff"));
    }
}

main()
{
// construct graph
graph_t g;

// read edges from file
read(g,"input.txt");

// display edges
display(g);
return 0;
}
```

with this input

```
John Bob Mike
Emma Noah Ava
Ben Henry Sarah
Lucas Mike Sophia
MissCongeality John Emma Ben Lucas
```

gives this output

| v1 | v2 | atribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Bob | bf |
| John | Mike | ff |
| Emma | Noah | bf |
| Emma | Ava | ff |
| Ben | Henry | bf |
| Ben | Sarah | ff |
| Lucas | Mike | bf |
| Lucas | Sophia | ff |
| MissCongeality | John | bf |
| MissCongeality | Emma | ff |
| MissCongeality | Ben | ff |
| MissCongeality | Lucas | ff |